# comparison of two dimensional array to a one dimension array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

I am stuck in this case, 
i have to compare a row of a two dimensional array to a one dimensional array. both arrays have characters like + and - and D. to be usable both arrays (the row and the single array) should match perfectly, but if any have the character D (for doubtful) it should be considered as inclusive
 eg.
     {+,-,d}   compared to   {+,-,-},
                             {+,-,d},
                             {+,d,d}
the program should return the row numbers of 2 and 3.

Comment: Please try to post the code or algorithm you are using this gives better understanding of your problems and approach you are following.

Comment: Use an outer `for` loop like `for (int rowNumber ...` which runs between 0 and the vertical dimension of the 2D array. Then inside this have another `for` loop like `for (int position ...` where position measures the horizontal position of both the 2D array and the 1D array which is our to-be-searched-for row. Then compare `arr2D[rowNumber, position]` to the `arr1D[position]` and check if everything is OK in the inner loop. When the inner loop has finished, you know if you must yield the current `rowNumber` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
var mat = new[,] {{'-','+','d'},{'-','-','d'},{'-','d','+'}};
var arr = new[] {'d','-','+'};

var matHeight = mat.GetLength(0);
var validRows = new List<int>();

for (int y = 0; y < matHeight; y++)
{
    bool isRowValid = true;

    for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
    {
        if (mat[y, x] != 'd' && arr[x] != 'd' && mat[y, x] != arr[x])
        {
            isRowValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isRowValid)
    {
        validRows.Add(y);
    }
}

foreach (var y in validRows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row {0} is valid", y);
    // will print 1 and 2 (two last rows indices)
}
```

I suggest using array of arrays (jagged array) rather than two dimensional array, though.

Comment: It wasn't me - but since SO isn't a code generating machine it's considered bad to answer "questions" like this (without showing own effort, without a useful question at all, some more or less weird description, doesn't care for comments, ...)

Comment: (didn't downvote!) Your `mat.Length` is a typo for `mat.GetLength(0)`.

Comment: @JeffRSon You're right, I was just bored and found some coding to do.

Comment: @JeffRSon While I agree that an asker cannot _expect_ to get (useful) answers if he shows no effort in the question, is it really "wrong" to actually write an answer to a question which has issues?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Sometimes I personally feel like educating the OP rather than helping with his actual question. Sometimes the opposite. It's all about vibes. In this case, I felt like an example code will get him started. OP still has lots to refactor, and I hope he will go over it and actually understand it instead of copy-paste-fiddle.

Comment: Well, I guess that could lead to a broad discussion or flame war. One point is, you don't really help that person. You solve this one problem, but the next is waiting around the corner (especially if it's a problem that's so simple). Another point is if you answer the right question if there isn't one. For example, what's the thing with "2 and 3"? OTOH, I think your comment above fits well: explain what to do (if the OP doesn't know how to get started) instead of giving ready-made code.

Comment: By the way, for a multi-dimensional array `mat`, the property `mat.Length` exists and returns the _product_ of all the `mat.GetLength(i)` where `i` runs from `0` to the "rank" of the array.

Comment: @JeffRSon I intentionally made this code with low spoonfeedablility. I was lazy to explain in human words. I assumed this was better than nothing. I liked doing it.

Comment: Ok i guess you guys have the right of it.. my question wasnt very clear.
the system is for bacteriological diagnosis. in the process of detecting a pathogen from a unknown colony, scientists use biochemical tests. the results of which are usually positive + or negative - or doubtful D. rows of the 2D array represent a set of characteristics of a certain pathogen. the point is to compare the pattern of biochemical results to our results. reason why i cannot use a simple for each type loop is that if a result is ever doubtful, that pathogen has to be considered as possible. 
2 and 3 means rows

Comment: what i tried to do was take the first row of the 2D array (the "control") in to a separate single dimension array and compare it with the results of my test (the "test" array) using for each loop. i also tried the two for loop approach.  all i wanted to find out was weather there is a standard way of doing it..